# Last access timestamp updated every 24 hours

Tags: files, date, timestamp

The last access timestamp of my files is updated every 24 hours whenever I access an files. E.g. I type "ls" and if the last access timestamp of the file is older than 24 it is updated to the current date.

Has anyone else the same phenomenon and any idea what is causing it. I have a SSD, perhaps it is related to this.

Comment: Do you have an indexer running that indexes all your files for faster searching? I believe the default Ubuntu installation does this. (Not running Unity, so can't really provide an answer)

Comment: `updatedb` (from `mlocate`, installed by default) runs daily. Try either temporarily removing it or disabling `/etc/cron.daily/mlocate`.

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini updatedb would only update directory timestamps, never timestamps on regular files, since it only indexes file names and not file content.

Comment: @Gilles: you're right. Sorry!

Comment: Does this still happens?

Comment: Which services have run on your system?

Comment: This might be related to this patch: https://lkml.org/lkml/2008/12/13/11 since relatime is used in Ubuntu and is particularly suited for SSDs

Answer (score 2):

If you have a SSD, the `relatime` mount option is automatically set. Here is what it does ([source](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Power_Management_Guide/Relatime.html)):

> Relatime maintains atime data, but not for each time that a file is accessed. With this option enabled, atime data is written to the disk only if the file has been modified since the atime data was last updated (mtime), or if the file was last accessed more than a certain length of time ago (by default, one day).

Try changing `relatime` to `noatime` in your `/etc/fstab` file to confirm the reason for these updates.