# Why is unity-files-daemon accessing my files once per day?

Tags: unity

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [All files in home folder have been accessed at (almost) same time](https://askubuntu.com/questions/249960/all-files-in-home-folder-have-been-accessed-at-almost-same-time)

All my files in my home folder are accessed recursively once per day (last access timestamp is set). With the help of audit, i found that the unity-files-daemon is doing this. Can anyone tell me why this is happening and if others are experiencing this also. Here is an excerpt from the audit log:

```
type=PATH msg=audit(02.02.2013 19:25:38.039:2250) : item=0 name=/home/rosa/Dokumente/test inode=2058 dev=08:03 mode=file,664 ouid=rosa ogid=rosa rdev=00:00 
type=CWD msg=audit(02.02.2013 19:25:38.039:2250) :  cwd=/ 
type=SYSCALL msg=audit(02.02.2013 19:25:38.039:2250) : arch=x86_64 syscall=open success=yes exit=9 a0=2451940 a1=40000 a2=0 a3=0 items=1 ppid=1 pid=6391 auid=rosa uid=rosa gid=rosa euid=rosa suid=rosa fsuid=rosa egid=rosa sgid=rosa fsgid=rosa tty=(none) ses=19 comm=unity-files-dae exe=/usr/lib/unity-lens-files/unity-files-daemon key=rosa
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's used for Ubuntu's file scope. It is used to index your files so that you can quickly search for them in the Dash and also show relevant information like sizes, thumbnails, recently used files.. etc.

Don't worry: It's not scanning your files for personal information whatsoever, and the collected information will not be send over the internet. It's only used for local purposes, to make your live a little bit easier.

If you are still concerned about your privacy, you can select what Ubuntu is logging by going to System Settings > Privacy. In there, click on the tab called Files to select what Ubuntu should avoid.

Comment: I already did that (excluded the /home-Folder and marked all checkboxes). But that didn't help.